# Copy Column A, insert for every other column, then sort

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating VBA code that takes data, compies the date column (column A) inserts for every, then for every pair of columns, it sorts it.

The data starts off like so

```
Date, A, B, C, ...
01/02/2019, 100, 110, 120, ...
02/02/2019, 101, 107, 124, ...
03/02/2019, 102, 107, 123, ...
04/02/2019, 101, 108, 123, ...
```

First it should insert the date as per

```
Date, A, Date, B, Date, C, ...
01/02/2019, 100, 01/02/2019, 110, 01/02/2019, 120, ...
02/02/2019, 101, 02/02/2019, 107, 02/02/2019, 124, ...
03/02/2019, 102, 03/02/2019, 107, 03/02/2019, 123, ...
04/02/2019, 101, 04/02/2019, 108, 04/02/2019, 123, ...
```

Then it should take columns in pairs, and sort by the second column i.e

```
Date,  A,  Date,  B,  Date,  C,  ...
01/02/2019, 100,  02/02/2019, 107,  01/02/2019, 120,  ...
02/02/2019, 101,  03/02/2019, 107,  03/02/2019, 123,  ...
04/02/2019, 101,  04/02/2019, 108,  04/02/2019, 123,  ...
03/02/2019, 102,  01/02/2019, 110,  02/02/2019, 124, ...
```

So far I have got code that finds the last column in a row, which returns the laast column as a string reference (e.g. "GM")

```
Function ColumnLetter() As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim LastColumnStr, ColumnPaste As String
    Dim p As Long

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("srtData")

    LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    Dim n As Long
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    n = LastColumn
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s
End Function
```

However I have no idea, how to iterate and then sort by second column. Ideallly I just want to have a function such as 
`Function sortallData(dim wsTest as String)` where I can just call the function by inputting the sheet name.

Comment: Break it down into tasks. Looks like you have to insert some columns, copy column A and then do some sorting.

Comment: Iterating for every other column is easily achievable with a simple `For...Next` loop like `For i = 1 to 15 Step 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I actually followed Tims advice. I split this into 3 different scripts, one iterates by selecting a column, pasting and inserting. The next then sorts each column.